# Log4J 1.2 PropertyConfigurator -> Log4J2

Tags: java, log4j2

Currently, our application uses Log4J 1.2 and configures it using either

```
File file = ...
PropertyConfigurator.configure(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

or

```
URL url = ...
PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
```

I know that the property file format has changed from 1.2 to 2, but what would be a similar way to configure Log4J 2 using a property file at an arbitrary file or URL?

Comment: You're asking if it's better to use a file or a URL?

Comment: No, we use both for different applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Log4J 2's documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#reconfig_from_code):

```
// import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File("path/to/a/different/log4j2.xml");

// this will force a reconfiguration
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Make sure to refer to [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html) (defined in the `log4j-core` artifact, not the `log4j-api` one) and **not** to [`org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, `LoggerContext` has no method `setConfigLocation`: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/LoggerContext.html Maybe the warning **Be aware that this LoggerContext class is not part of the public API so your code may break with any minor release** became true. Shouldn't something simple like that be public API?

Comment: @ThomasS. You're linking to `org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext`. The code mentions [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html) in `log4j-core`.

Comment: Ah, the same class name used in different packages. That is tricky. Thanks.

Comment: How to do this if my code is using a Properties object instead of a file for configuration

Answer (score 7):

You can use `PropertiesConfigurationBuilder` as follows:

```
// Custom-loaded properties.
Properties props = ... 
// Beware it should be org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext class,
// not the one ins spi package!
// Not sure about the meaning of "false".
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder()
            .setConfigurationSource(ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE)
            .setRootProperties(props)
            .setLoggerContext(context)
            .build();
 context.setConfiguration(config);
 Configurator.initialize(config);
```

It's true that using the `core` classes looks like a hack but the author himself uses them in his tutotrial: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/manual/customconfig.html .