# Migrating from log4j v1 to v2.16.0

Tags: migration, log4j, log4j2

I’m  migrating from log4j version 1.x to 2.x. I’ve made all the changes I needed to according to
[https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#] but cannot find the equivalent for the following:

`1. LogManager.resetConfiguration()`

`2. PropertyConfigurator.configure()`
Been through countless documentation and internet resources but can’t figure it out. Appreciate any help!

Comment: https://log4j-user.logging.apache.narkive.com/G4W8vSKU/logmanager-resetconfiguration-in-log4j2 has an answer about resetConfiguration - btw log4j 2.17.0 is now out with another CVE fix

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115143/log4j-1-2-propertyconfigurator-log4j2 covers the PropertyConfigurator.configure() question